# Meaning of the verb "read" in various tenses

Tags: meaning, tense

> 1. Have you already read the book? Yes, I have already read the book.

Does it mean that the person have read the entire/whole book to the end? Or it is not necessary and generally depends on context?

> 2. Did you read the book? Yes, I did.

As far as I guess it usually means "read entire the book" whereas "I read a part of the book" usually can be expressed by the past continouse tense: "I was reading the book". Am I right?

> 3. Haven't you read the book, yet? Yes, I haven't read the book.

In contrast to the first sentence, which implies the two meanings, the last sentence defintely means that I even didn't "open" the book. Because if I read a part of the book then I have read a book of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's confirm that "*the* book" would normally imply the *whole* book.

If someone asks "did you read the book?", the most likely answers are:

- Yes, I read it (completed it)
- No, I didn't read it (not touched it)
- I am reading it (starting, but not completed)

When asking "*haven't*" you done something, rather than asking "*have*" you done it, there is certainly a different inference in the *question*:

- Have you read the book? (an open question, no assumption)
- Haven't you read the book? (a question that assumes you haven't and seeks to confirm that assumption)

However, the potential *answers* should be *no different*:

Q. Haven't you read the book?
A. Yes I have / No I haven't / I'm still reading it.

Comment: Does the answer "No I haven't" exclude the case "I have read only a part of the book"? According to the answer of @Jack O'Flaherty It doesn't. Though there is the answer "I'am still reading it" in this case.

Comment: @xyz I don't suppose saying "I haven't read it" *excludes* the possibility they started it but haven't finished... but I think that if you'd read a substantial part of it and intended to finish it you would say so, wouldn't you? That's not really an English language question, more a question of how much you want to tell someone.

Comment: Note that "the whole book" might not literally be every page; eg., even though I haven't read the appendices, I would be well within common US usage to say that I've read _The Lord of the Rings_.

Comment: @xyz You misunderstood my answer. "No I haven't." means that "I have read the book." is not true.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2:  If you say "I have read the book.", it means you have read the entire book. If you have read only part of the book, you would say "some of the book", or "part of the book".

3. The answer "Yes, I haven't read the book." is not idiomatic. "Haven't you read the book yet?" would be answered by either
   3a "Yes, I have read the book."  or
   3b "No, I haven't read the book."

The negative answer (3b) means that I didn't read the whole book. It doesn't mean that you didn't open it or read part of it.

Comment: I would say that 3 is not only unidiomatic, it is also ungrammatical.

Comment: @NotThatGuy You think "Yes, I haven't read the book yet." is idiomatic?  I do not.

Comment: It reminds me of this: "Yes, we have no bananas". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrkgzbIjJdg

Comment: @NotThatGuy Oh, I see. The question is fine. I'll clarify my answer.